# ¿crear evento mysql que consulte los registro de una tabla y dependiendo del resultado los inserte en otra?

Tags: mysql, select, eventos, insert, sql

Estoy tratando de realizar un evento que se ejecute todos los días a las 11:59 pm. Que me consulte los registros(codigo) de una tabla(tblpuntoAtencion) y con el resultado haga una especie de foreach, sume el valor de otra una tabla agrupado por codigo(registros consultados anteriormente) y dependiendo del estado que es 1 y reste datos de la misma tabla dependiendo el estado que es 2 y sumándole otro valor de  otra tabla(tblrecaudo), por cada registro que se encuentre, me inserte los datos en otra tabla(tblsaldos). Espero me puedan ayudar. Estas son las tablas y algunos registros:

He realizado algunas consultas, pero no sé como hacer el ciclo para que, por cada registro que esté en la `tblpuntoAtencion`, se guarde en los datos en la  tblSaldo

```
CREATE TABLE tblenvios (
  idEnvio int(11) NOT NULL,
  valor double NOT NULL,
  fecha date NOT NULL,
  estado enum('1','2') NOT NULL,
  puntoA_E int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO tblenvios (idEnvio, valor, fecha, estado, puntoA_E) VALUES
(100001, 50000, '2019-03-18', '1', 8000),
(100002, 80000, '2019-03-18', '1', 8000),
(100003, 100000, '0000-00-00', '2', 8000),
(100004, 60000, '2019-03-18', '1', 8002);


CREATE TABLE tblpuntoatencion (
  id int(11) NOT NULL,
  codigo int(11) NOT NULL,
  barrio varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO tblpuntoatencion (id, codigo, barrio) VALUES
(1, 8000, 'Bosque'),
(2, 8001, 'Mercado'),
(3, 8002, 'Palmeras');


CREATE TABLE tblrecaudo (
  idRecaudo int(11) NOT NULL,
  valorRecaudo double NOT NULL,
  fecha date NOT NULL,
  puntoA int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO tblrecaudo (idRecaudo, valorRecaudo, fecha, puntoA) VALUES
(1, 30000, '2019-03-16', 8000),
(2, 20000, '2019-03-18', 8000),
(3, 40000, '2019-03-18', 8001);


CREATE TABLE tblsaldo (
  idSaldo int(11) NOT NULL,
  codigoPa int(11) NOT NULL,
  saldo int(11) NOT NULL,
  fecha int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



**tblPuntoAtencion**
    ----------------------------------------------------------
    id  codigo  barrio
    1   8000  bosque
    2   8001  mercado
    3   8002  palmeras
    -----------------------------------------------

    **tblEnvios**
    -------------------------------------------
    idEnvio   valor   fecha        estado  puntoA_E
    100001    50000   18-03-2019     1  8000
    100002    80000   18-03-2019     1  8000
    100003   100000   18-03-2019     2  8000
    100004    60000   18-03-2019     1  8002
    -----------------------------------------------------

    **tblrecaudo**
    ----------------------------------------------------
    idrecaudo   valorRecaudo   fecha        puntoA
    1   30000               2019-03-16    8000
    2   20000               2019-03-18    8000
    3   40000               2019-03-18    8001
    ----------------------------------------------------------
```

Aquí quiero que se guarden los registros:

```
**tblsaldo** 
idSaldo
codigoPa
saldo
fecha
```

En la `tblEnvios` suma valor con estado 1 por puntoA_E y fecha actual y le resta el valor con estado 2 por puntoA, fecha actual y se le suma valorRecaudo de la `tblrecaudo` por puntoA y fecha actual "suponiendo que la fecha actual es 2019-03-18"

Ejemplo:

```
codigo  valor     estado  -   codigo  valor     estado  +  puntoA   valorRecaudo  =  puntoA   total
8000    130000     1      -   8000    100000     2      +  8000     20000         =  8000     50000

**resultados esperados**
puntoA  total  fechaactual
8000    50000  2019-03-18
8001    40000  2019-03-18
8002    60000  2019-03-18
```

Y estos datos se guarden en la tabla `tblsaldo`

```
SELECT codigo FROM tblpuntoAtencion
```

Con este código puedo obtener los códigos de los puntos de atención:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN E.puntoA_E = 8000 AND E.estado = 1 THEN E.valor ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN E.puntoA_E = 8000 AND E.estado = 2 THEN E.valor ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN R.puntoA = 8000 THEN R.valorRecaudo ELSE 0 END) AS total FROM tblenvios E,tblrecaudo R where E.puntoA_E=R.puntoA AND R.fecha ='2019-03-18' AND E.fecha ='2019-03-18' order by puntoA_E;
```

Con esta consulta me trae el resultado de la sumatoria de la `tblEnvios` y `tblrecaudo`
     pero faltaría algo porque no me arroja el dato exacto ayuda en esta parte

```
     Tratando de hacer el evento:

            CREATE EVENT guardaSaldo
                ON SCHEDULE
                EVERY 1 day STARTS '2019-03-18 23:59:00' + interval 1 day do
                begin
                    SELECT codigo FROM tblpuntoAtencion;
            foreach (CODIGO as COD) {
       SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN E.puntoA_E = COD AND E.estado = 1 THEN E.valor ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN E.puntoA_E = COD AND E.estado = 2 THEN E.valor ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN R.puntoA = COD THEN R.valorRecaudo ELSE 0 END) AS total FROM tblenvios E,tblrecaudo R where E.puntoA_E=R.puntoA AND R.fecha ='2019-03-18' AND E.fecha ='2019-03-18' order by puntoA_E;

INSERT INTO tblsaldo(codigoPa,saldo,fecha) VALUES(8000,50000,'2019-03-18')
                end;
    }

    el **foreach** es para hacerme entender de lo que quiero hacer

    No sé cómo hacer que haga la consulta de todos los puntoA y los inserte los datos en la tabla tblsaldo de forma dinamica
```

Comment: Bienvenido por favor lee [ask], edita y coloca tu contenido en forma de texto y no de imagen, además de eso por favor añade que llevas hecho o investigado

Comment: Es preferible que tu codigo este como texto en lugar de como imagen. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324)

Comment: ¿Qué te parece si añades la estructura de la base de datos en SQL (con phpMyAdmin, Exportar)? También puedes utilizar Ctrl+k después de marcar el código para que quede más legible :)

Comment: Editando tu pregunta he visto que te faltaba un punto y coma (;) tras la primera consulta del evento. En cualquier caso, no nos pasas el SQL con el que generas las tablas. Para reproducir tu base de datos tendríamos que hacerlo nosotros y tú ya lo tienes hecho. Por favor, facilítanoslo :)

Comment: El SQL aportado no contenía los mismos datos que las tablas de la pregunta y las consultas no funcionaban por ambigüedad en el campo fecha. Lo he unificado en la edición que te he propuesto y aún así no consigo entender qué quieres hacer. Ahora que tenemos el mismo dataset intenta aclararlo un poco modificando de nuevo la pregunta, a ver si puedo ayudarte. La duda está en la parte de ejemplo con el recaudo, el punto A, el estado 2... no me aclaro.

Comment: hola David ya he corregido algunos errores tambien coloque la estructura de la bd y las consultas. lo que quiero hacer es un evento que se ejecute todos los dias que seleccione todos los puntosAtencion con ese resultado hacer un for que valla sumando todos los envios con estado 1 y le reste los envios con estado 2 y le sume los recaudos, los ordene por codigo de puntoAntencion y con la fecha actual espero me pueda hacer entender el codigo esta corregido y el foreach es para dar una idea

Comment: ayuda por favor

Comment: Porque queres hacer un procedimiento? esto se puede resolver con un query directamente. Hay algun problema con eso?

Comment: lo que quiero es que se ejecute a media noche y calcule el saldo de cada punto de atención me puedes explicar como hacerlo por favor o darme una idea

Comment: que otra manera puedo conseguir lo que quiero hacer por favor

Comment: En que lenguaje lo necesitas? Solo quieres SQL o puedes meterlo en un script, PHP por ejemplo, y pasarlo al cron del server?

Comment: preferiblemente sql ya que nose como colocarlo en el cron les agradezco mucho la ayuda Bendiciones